# TextView changes value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While returning Spinner selected value from Blank Activity to Second Activity, it works as the text in Second Activity changes. But when I go back to First Activity and then come back to Second Activity, it loses its value.

**FirstActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mButton= null;
    int order=0;
    String status="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    mButton = findViewById(R.id.goSecondActivity);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i= new Intent(view.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "About Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.contact:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by NIHIR on 10-01-2018.
 */

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button mButton = null;
private Button mDetailButton = null;
private TextView mSelectedView = null;
private Bundle extras = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    mButton = findViewById(R.id.goFirstActivity);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mDetailButton = findViewById(R.id.goDetailActivity);

    mDetailButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("KeyForSending", "Some Data from Second Activity");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mSelectedView = findViewById(R.id.userSelection);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
        String myValue= extras.getString("KeyForReturning");
        if(myValue!=null){
            mSelectedView.setText(myValue);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "About Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.contact:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by NIHIR on 10-01-2018.
 */

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner mSpinner= null;
private Bundle extras = null;
private Button mReturnButton= null;
private Button mPerformButton= null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null){
        String detailValue = extras.getString("KeyForSending");
        if( detailValue != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, detailValue,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    mSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelector);
    mReturnButton= findViewById(R.id.returnToSecondActivity);
    mReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            String mySelection = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            returnIntent.putExtra("KeyForReturning", mySelection);
            startActivity(returnIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

How can I change TextView in SecondActivity to the spinner selection from third activity so that it doesn't change even if I go back to FirstActivity?

Comment: "But when I go back to First Activity and then come back to Second Activity, it loses its value." - that's because you do not "come back to Second Activity": you start a new instance of SecondActivity. So AFAIK  the easiest way is to persist the selection (e.g. in SharedPreferences if it's just one value or in the SQLite database if there will be lots of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SecondActivity, save the instance state and instead of getting the value from extra, get it from savedInstanceState in the onCreate method.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("KeyForReturning", mSelectedView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}



if(savedInstanceState != null){
  String myValue = savedInstanceState.getString("KeyForReturning");
  if(myValue != null){
    mSelectedView.setText(myValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you're going from **DetailActivity** to **SecondActivity**, you're passing the value back, which is why it is shown in **SecondActivity**, but when you close it and go back to **FirstActivity** and then to **SecondActivity**, you're not passing any intent.

Just so you know, once you close an activity (via **finish()** or **Back Button**, it loses all its data (unless of course you're saving it off somewhere) and is recreated as a new instance.

That's the explanation to why you're not getting what you want. To persist the data save it in **SharedPreferences** or anywhere you like and then it'll be available to you as long as you want.